# How can I implement a Markov chain that purges old data when it consumes too much memory?

Tags: python, memory-management

Awhile ago I wrote a [Markov chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) text generator for IRC in Python. It would consume all of my VPS's free memory after running for a month or two and I would need to purge its data and start over. Now I'm rewriting it and I want to tackle the memory issue as elegantly as possible.

The data I have to keep trimmed down is a generally a dictionary that maps strings to lists of strings. More specifically, each word in a message is mapped to all the possible subsequent words. This is still an oversimplification, but it's sufficient for contextualizing my problem.

Currently, the solution I'm wrestling with involves managing "buckets" of data. It would keep track of each bucket's apparent size, "archive" a bucket once it's reached a certain size and move on to a new one, and after 5 or so buckets it would delete the oldest "archived" bucket every time a new one is created. This has the advantage of simplicity: removing an entire bucket doesn't create any dead-ends or unreachable words because the words from each message all go into the same bucket.

The problem is that "keeping track of each bucket's apparent size" is easier said than done.

I first tried using `sys.getsizeof`, but quickly found that it's impractical for determining the object's *actual* size in memory. I've also looked into guppy / heapy / various other memory usage modules, but none of them seem to do what I'm looking for (i.e. benchmark a single object). Currently I'm experimenting with the lower-level [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) module. Here's an excerpt from the current state of the application:

```
class Markov(object):
    # (constants declared here)
    def __init__(self):
        self.proc = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
        self.buckets = []
        self._newbucket()

    def _newbucket(self):
        self.buckets.append(copy.deepcopy(self.EMPTY_BUCKET))

    def _checkmemory(f):
        def checkmemory(self):
            # Check memory usage of the process and the entire system
            if (self.proc.get_memory_percent() > self.MAX_MEMORY
                    or psutil.virtual_memory().percent > self.MAX_TOTAL_MEMORY):
                self.buckets.pop(0)
            # If we just removed the last bucket, add a new one
            if not self.buckets:
                self._newbucket()
            return f()
        return checkmemory

    @_checkmemory
    def process(self, msg):
        # generally, this adds the words in msg to self.buckets[-1]

    @_checkmemory
    def generate(self, keywords):
        # generally, this uses the words in all the buckets to create a sentence
```

The problem here is that this will only expire buckets; I have no idea when to "archive" the current bucket because Python's overhead memory prevents me from accurately determining how far I am from hitting `self.MAX_MEMORY`. Not to mention that the `Markov` class is actually one of many "plugins" being managed by a headless IRC client (another detail I omitted for brevity's sake), so the overhead is not only present, but unpredictable.

In short: **is there a way to accurately benchmark single Python objects?** Alternatively, if you can think of a better way to 'expire' old data than my bucket-based solution, I'm all ears.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing the point entirely, but shouldn't you just use a database system?

Comment: You could use an in-memory data store with self-expiration options, like Redis, or a fixed size list/queue that pops stuff out of the tail end on each insert once it reaches its maximum allowable size. Neither option accounts for varying object size, but you can probably estimate an upper limit for the size and go from there.

Comment: @Nisan.H: Redis looks interesting, but I don't think TTLs would be appropriate for my situation because I can't predict the rate at which messages will be received. I'll keep it in mind for future projects, though.

Comment: @AlptiginJalayr: Possibly. I hadn't considered it because I don't often use databases outside of web development, but I'll investigate how feasible it is for my purposes.

Comment: @Fraxtil would a collection object with a definable max size and bindable action on tail-end pops (once full size is reached) work for your use case? Something along the lines of "once collection reaches 1000 members, pop the oldest member upon any new insert and execute ArchiveBuffer(member) on it. Once Archive reaches a size of 100, flush it to the end of the archive file." I'll write it up in an answer, but it's slightly involved and I want to make sure it's headed in the right direction for your problem first.

Comment: For what it's worth, given a large enough data footprint, I think there's a lot of power that can be leveraged from using a database.

Comment: Since the data you're keeping is essentially a "dictionary that maps strings to lists of strings", its size will be proportional to the length of the key string plus the sum of the length of all the strings in the list -- so just keep track of that to get an estimate of its total size or at least something proportional to it. Doesn't seem like there's a need for an exact value (or a database), just use the simplest thing that works.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit of a hacky solution, but if your bucket objects are pickleable (and it sounds like they are), you could pickle them and measure the byte-length of the pickled object string. It may not be exactly the size of the unpacked object in memory, but it should grow linearly as the object grows and give you a fairly good idea of relative size between objects.

To prevent having to pickle really large objects, you can measure the size of each entry added to the bucket by pickling it on its own, and adding its bytelength to the bucket's total bytelength attribute. 
Bear in mind, though, that if you do this there will be some overhead memory used in the internal bindings of the entry and the bucket that will not be reflected by the independent size of the entry itself, but you can run some tests to profile this and figure out what the %memory overhead is going to be for each new entry beyond its actual size.

Comment: This has some good ideas, particularly the notion of profiling to determine overhead costs. I might try creating a subprocess that generates a large data set, observes the change in memory consumption, and divides that by the size of the pickled data. If that ends up working I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Sounds good. Bear in mind that there may also be additional memory usage issues (in the python process itself) from pickling. In fact, while testing, I would try to pickle directly into a StringIO file or a network socket to avoid as much of this as possible.

Comment: I would only measure the process's memory usage immediately before and after creation of the dataset; pickling the data would come after that's already been done. There are probably a few other oddities I'm overlooking like allocation for the variable's name or string interning, but they're minor enough that I'm not too concerned about them.